# How to see live what is uploaded into a folder php

Tags: javascript, php, session, upload, live

Good afternoon,

I have opened the page in my phone where I can upload files into a specific folder on my server and the same the page which shows what is uploaded into the folder is opened on my pc. To see the new files i have to refresh the page! How can i make it showing every file which is uploaded live ? I prefer php but idk js maybe jquery ??

Many thanks,
Mark

Comment: Did you take a look at node.js or web sockets?

Comment: No, I have built the page with php and I don't know how to do it with js :(